# How do you document a description for a custom class in Objective-C/Swift?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I know you can use /// (triple slash) to comment variables and even use `/**` for doxygen style comments on functions and the like, but is there a way to document a custom class itself? So if someone were to option-click it in Xcode there would be a description?

Comment: Just put those `///` comments before the declaration of the class (i.e. before  the `class` statement in Swift, or before the `@interface` in Objective-C). Note the syntax for documenting functions, though, differs in the two languages. In Objective-C you use the doxygen-style, where as Swift [has its own style](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/).

Comment: Swift comments are written in a subset of ReStructured Text.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and found the solution.

1. You use @file tag(or \file tag) when you want to make a comment for custom class with Doxygen. 
   (This is a recommended way in Doxygen Document site, but it is often overlooked.)
2. write a comment you want with tag

That's it.

For example :

```
/*!
@file CustomViewController.h
*/
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

/*!
 @brief The CustomViewController Header file

 @discussion CustomVC

 @superclass SuperClass: UIViewController
 @classdesign    No special design is applied here.
 @coclass    AppDelegate
 @helps It helps no other classes.
 @helper    No helper exists for this class.
 @author dakeshi
 @version 1.0
*/

@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController
```

** I tested this code with Xcode 6.2

You can recognize the @file tag is seperated. Doxygen can not generate document what I want to if I moved the @file tag in the second comment block. It's only working perfectly @file tag is described alone.(I can not find the reason yet.)

You can use @class, @protocol tag in second comment block, but you need to use it very carefully. Some tags have to use with newline.(e.g. @discussion, @class) because Apple has reserved keywords that are same name of some tags). If you use @class tag without newline in above example, you just could see a normal apple documentation about UIViewController.

Answer (score -2):

You can document with different ways like

```
/*!
 * @discussion <#description#>
 * @param <#param description#>
 * @return <#return description#>
 */
```

See detailed description of `@discussion` key words and how to use these comments fastly using code snippets in below link

http://www.raywenderlich.com/66395/documenting-in-xcode-with-headerdoc-tutorial

Comment: You can use `HeaderDoc Tags` repeatedly to document your class some of tags are only for functions. But `@disscussion` `@brief` works for classes also. Or you can use

`/**
 * Your documentation comment will go here
 */
`
before `@interface` to tell calss description